# Shopify Python Get Theme asset as CSS from .scss.liquid file

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

Is it possible to **externally** (from my non-embedded Shopify app) perform an API call that will emulate the functionality of the `asset_url` liquid tag and compile / process a `.scss.liquid` file into `.css` so that I can use it in an external app?

My app lives at `subdomain.myapp.com` and I want to be able to include the stores css files so that I can apply typography settings etc. from the store.

Presently I am getting the theme asset like so:

```
current_theme = shopify.Theme.find_first(role="main")
theme_css = shopify.Asset.find(key='assets/theme.scss.liquid', 
    theme_id=current_theme.id)
```

I know I could use an app proxy to embedd this page into Shopify, but I want to access the css outside of shopify.

Comment: Do you want to use the same styles in your App that Shopify has?

Comment: Yes, but without the layout like header and footer.

Comment: Use Shopify Polaris to develop your App (https://polaris.shopify.com/)

Comment: @SubhrajyotiDas that isn't an option as this app is not restricted to only Shopify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have answered your own question with your question. Since you can make API calls to get theme assets like stylesheets, you are then free to use them as you wish. There is no difference in authentication and authorization with embedded vs. non-embedded Apps.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think this is the case. The `theme.scss.liquid` file when requested still has liquid variables in it. As it is a liquid file. Also, the scss is not converted to css, so all the imports from other scss files are not compiled. The simple get request would work for other asset types (like images), but not for scss unfortunately.

Comment: Ahh. That is too bad. You are right... the .liquid files are not parsed when you request them. Thing is, Shopify does parse them and make them available as regular css files. Why not request an already parsed version?

Comment: If I do that I am thinking I will need to have to have my users manually enter the URL to an already parsed file. I was hoping I could just retrieve it automatically via the API.

Comment: Why would anyone have to interact with a CSS file and why would you need to present them with an URL? An URL to what?

Comment: How else am I going to find the location of the processed css file? It doesn't exist in the theme files. It only exists once an asset tag refers to it through liquid.

Comment: So you are saying an asset theme.scss.liquid does not product an asset theme.css? Since when? Just download the asset using the API. Why would you need an URL? Only the front-end uses an URL to an asset, not an API call.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182521/discussion-between-coler-j-and-david-lazar).